# Writing non ASCII characters to stdout with write() function in c

Tags: c

I have been trying to write non ASCII characters like `ğ`, `ç`, `ş` to `stdout` with using the `write()` function. When I try to write them to `stdout` from a string literal something confused me.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "ğğğ";
    
    write(1, &str[0], 1);
    write(1, &str[1], 1);
}
```

In that program, I expected that it should first write 8-bit of `'ğ'` character to `stdout` and then write the second 8-bit of it due to 2 byte presence of `'ğ'` character. However, it only writes one `'ğ'` character to `stdout`. I can't figure out how it combines two different write functions outputs. Same thing also happens when I use the `printf` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "ğğğ";
    
    printf("%c", str[0]);
    printf("%c", str[1]);
}
```

In that code it also prints one `'ğ'` character.

Same thing happens when I try to print other multi-byte characters. Why does this happen? Am I missing something very simple?

Comment: Each `ğ` character is actually 2 bytes due to UTF-8 encoding. `str[0]` is the first byte, `str[1]` is the second byte.

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Assumimg UTF-8 encoding, your program writes a byte `0xC4`, then `0x9F`. The terminal interprets the byte sequence according to the configured locale which results in a `'ğ'` character. The terminal does not know if the two bytes are written by a single `write` or by separate `write` calls.

Comment: The first thing to understand is that there are dozens if not hundreds of ways to represent non-ASCII text. Today, the most common way is UTF-8, except on Windows, Java, and JavaScript where UTF-16. 

The second thing to understand is that a C `char` isn't really a character, it's a byte. 

You're probably using UTF-8, which encodes `"ğ"` using two bytes. After you `write()` two bytes to stdout, you get `ğ` on the terminal. 

What's the value of `strlen("ğğğ")`? That should be informative for you.

Comment: " I expected that it should first write 8-bit of `'ğ'` character to `stdout` and then write the second 8-bit of it due to 2 byte presence of `'ğ'` character. However, it only writes one `'ğ'` character to stdout." i don't see how this should be a contradiction? How isn't that what you are expecting?

Comment: I suggest to `write` a buffer with a single-byte charcter before and after the two bytes of `ğ` and insert a delay, e.g. `sleep(2)` between all the `write` calls. Then you will see that nothing is displayed when the first byte is written, and the character appears after writing the second byte.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I know that the return value of `strlen("ğğğ")` is 6. But I was expecting output of this: `write(1, &str[0], 1);` would be an ASCII character which is the equivalence of the first 8 bit of the `ğ` character. Apart from that I know a `char` is a byte not a character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to encode non ASCII characters in the C source code, in the process memory and/or as a byte stream to/from the terminal.  Assuming your system uses UTF-8 for all 3, which is very common, especially on unix systems (linux, macOS), the character `ğ` is encoded as a 2 byte sequence `C4 9F`, so the string `"ğğğ"` actually occupies 6 bytes plus a null terminator.

To print a single `ğ`, you can use `write(1, "ğ", 2)` or simply `write(1, "ğ", strlen("ğ"))`.

When you issue 2 separate write calls for the individual bytes at `str[0]` and `str[1]`, the first outputs the UTF-8 lead byte 0xC4 and the second the trailing byte 0x9F. `str[1]` is not the second *character* in the string, it denotes the second byte of the character array `str` that has 7 bytes total. Writing the 2 byte sequence in a single or 2 write calls produces the same result on your terminal: a single `ğ` character.

The behavior is exactly the same for the `printf` calls: you output 2 bytes that form a single character `ğ`, (Unicode code point U-011F, encoded as `"\xC4\x9F"`).

Note that `'ğ'` is a malformed character constant, which is not portable and should not be used to represent the non-ASCII character. Some C compilers will parse it as a multibyte character constant, like `'abc'`, which is a confusing historical oddity, while others such as **clang** will generate an error.

Here is a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *str = "ğ";
    const wchar_t *wstr = L"ğ";

    printf("str: \"%s\"\n", str);
    printf("strlen(\"%s\"): %zu\n", str, strlen(str));
    printf("sizeof \"%s\": %zu\n", "ğ", sizeof "ğ");
    printf("str[0]: 0x%02hhX, str[1]: 0x%02hhX\n", str[0], str[1]);

    //this generates an error:
    //  character too large for enclosing character literal type
    //printf("'%s' = %#x\n", str, 'ğ');

    printf("wstr: L\"%s\"\n", str);
    printf("wclen(L\"%s\"): %zu\n", str, wcslen(wstr));
    printf("sizeof L\"%s\": %zu\n", str, sizeof L"ğ");
    printf("wstr[0]: 0x%04X\n", wstr[0]);

    printf("sizeof L\'%s\': %zu\n", str, sizeof L'ğ');
    printf("L'%s' = 0x%04X\n", str, L'ğ');

    return 0;
}
```

Output on macOS:

```
str: "ğ"
strlen("ğ"): 2
sizeof "ğ": 3
str[0]: 0xC4, str[1]: 0x9F
wstr: L"ğ"
wclen(L"ğ"): 1
sizeof L"ğ": 8
wstr[0]: 0x011F
sizeof L'ğ': 4
L'ğ' = 0x011F
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From my perspective (which is wrong possibly) the output of this: `write(1, &str[0], 1);` should be an 8-bit ASCII character which is the equivalence of the first 8-bit of the `'ğ'` character.

Comment: `write(1, &str[0], 1)` indeed outputs the first byte of the 2 byte representation of `ğ` in the string `str`, which is **not** an ASCII character, it is a non-ASCII byte `C4` interpreted by the terminal as the leading byte of a 2-byte UTF-8 sequence. `write(1, &str[1], 1)` output the second byte of the sequence, namely `9F` and the terminal decodes the sequence `C4 9F` as the character `ğ`  and displays it.